# Take a list in input remove all duplicates and count how many they are

Tags: c

I have tried to make this function but sometimes I get a problem on runtime. I need to take in input a list like 1-2-3-2-4-6-1-2 and the list should be modified as 1-2-3-4-6 so once for every node and I should save how many times is a node repeated so for example 1 is repeated 2 times the 2 is repeated 3 times etc. 
But sometimes it doesn't work I cannot understand why.
If you run it following what I wrote just after you'll see the problem:
How many nodes: 5 than write 1, 1, 2, 4, 2 and the output should be 1, 2 -> 2, 2 -> 4 (that means 1 is repeated two times, 2 is repeated two times and 4 is repeated 1 time). If I give in input 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 I get the "right output" plus a garbage value. More are the numbers higher is the probability that it doesn't work :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
   int val;
   int rip;
   struct Node *next;
} node;

node *modify(node *head);

void print(node *head2);

int main(){

   int m, i;

   printf("How many nodes: \n");
   scanf("%d", &m);

   node *head = NULL;
   head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
   node *temp = head;
   node *head2 = NULL;
  for(i=0; i < m; i++){
       temp->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
       printf("Write the value in position %d: \n", i);
       scanf("%d", &temp->val);
       temp = temp->next;
       temp->next = NULL;  
   }

   head2 = modify(head);

   print(head2);

   return 0;
}

node *modify(node *head){

   int counter, pass, m;

   node *curr = head;
   node *track = head;

while (track->next != NULL){
       counter = 0;
       pass = 0;
       m = track->val;
       while((curr)->next != NULL){
           if(m == (curr)->val){
               pass++;
               counter++;
               if(pass > 1){
                   node *removed = curr;
                   curr = (curr)->next;
                   free(removed);
               }
               if(pass == 1)
                   curr = curr->next;
           }
           else{
               curr = (curr)->next;
           }    
       }
       track->rip = counter;
       track = track->next;
       curr = track;
   }

return head;
}

void print(node *head2){

   while(head2->next != NULL){
       printf("%d, %d -> ", head2->val, head2->rip);
       head2 = head2->next;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "doesn't work". Give the input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: ok, done it :-)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces   Note: this statement: `while (track->next != NULL){`  and `return head;`  do not conform to the 'consistent indenting' objective.  2)  please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: Those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers

Comment: OT: regarding; `head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions:  `malloc()`  `realloc()`  `calloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not succesful call `perror( "your error message" );` to output to `stderr` your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  This error is not recoverable, so cleanup and call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &temp->val);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure it matches the number of 'input format conversion' specifiers.

Comment: OT: please use meaningful variable names.  Names like `m` are meaningless, even in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int val;
    int rip;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

node *modify(node *head);

void print(node *head2);

int main(){

    int m, i;

    printf("How many nodes: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    node *head = NULL;
    head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *temp = head;
    node *head2 = NULL;

    printf("Write the value in HEAD position : \n");
    scanf("%d", &temp->val);
    temp->rip=0;
    temp->next = NULL;

    for(i=0; i < m-1; i++)
    {
        temp->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Write the value in position %d: \n", i);
        temp = temp->next;
        scanf("%d", &temp->val);
        temp->rip=0;
        temp->next = NULL;  
    }

    head2 = modify(head);

    print(head2);

    return 0;
}

node *modify(node *head){

    int counter, pass, m;

    node *curr = head;
    node *track = head;
    node *precNode;

    while (track != NULL){
        counter = 0;
        pass = 0;
        m = track->val;
        while( curr != NULL){
            if(m == (curr)->val){
                pass++;
                counter++;
                if(pass > 1){
                    node *removed = curr;

                    precNode->next = (curr)->next;

                    curr = (curr)->next;
                    free(removed);

                }
                if(pass == 1)
                {
                    precNode = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
            }
            else{
                precNode = curr;
                curr = (curr)->next;
            }    
        }
        track->rip = counter;
        track = track->next;
        curr = track;
    }

    return head;
}

void print(node *head2){

    while(head2 != NULL){
        printf("[%d, %d]  ->   ", head2->val, head2->rip);
        head2 = head2->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: [1/2]Thanks for your help guys. I have a question, I used this little function that I developed some time ago and this works perfectly and this is what I rewrote to remove numbers in my program above that you fixed, may I know what's the difference btw this function and the one I wrote before?

Comment: ```node_t *rimuovi(node_t *head, int x) {

    node_t **curr = &head;
    while (*curr != NULL) {
        if ((*curr)->val == x) {
            node_t *removed = *curr;
            *curr = (*curr)-> next;
            free(removed);
        } else {
            curr = &(*curr)->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}```

Comment: This worked perfectly but it seems that I'm not keeping track of the precedent value too, am I wrong?

Comment: @awwww Yes, you have the same problem also in this function: You don't have a reference to the precedente element, so you can not delete current element

Comment: This answer only posts a possible code sequence,  it does not describe the problem nor what/why the fix is needed

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
           if(pass > 1){
               node *removed = curr;
               curr = (curr)->next;
               free(removed);
           }
```

This code frees the node that should be removed but does not link the previous one to the next one, so the list becomes incorrect. As you do not re-use the freed memory, it keeps its previous values but you do invoke Undefined Behaviour by using it.

You will have to track the previous record to fix the links. A possible code could be:

```
while (track->next != NULL){
   counter = 0;
   pass = 0;
   node *old = NULL;
   m = track->val;
   curr = track;
   while((curr)->next != NULL){
       node *next = curr->next;
       if(m == (curr)->val){
           pass++;
           counter++;
           if(pass > 1){
               old->next = next;  // old cannot be NULL because pass>1
               free(curr);
               curr = NULL;
           }
       }
       if (curr != NULL) old = curr;
       curr = next;
   }
   track->rip = counter;
   track = track->next;
}
```